# Initialization Properties in Swift 2

Tags: ios, properties, initialization, swift2, self

I am trying to build a custom UIView and am lost as far as initialization goes.

**Code One**

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    var propertyToInitialize: CGRect

    //Custom Initializer
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
         self.propertyToInitialize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (superview?.frame.size.width)!, height: (superview?.frame.size.height)!)
         super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

When I use the above code the error XCode gives me is as follows.

**Error**

```
Use of 'self' property access 'superview' before super.init initializes self
```

So I modified my code

**Code Two**

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    var propertyToInitialize: CGRect

    //Custom Initializer
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
         self.propertyToInitialize = CGRect()
         super.init(frame: frame)
         self.propertyToInitialize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (superview?.frame.size.width)!, height: (superview?.frame.size.height)!)
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is this bad design? Should I take a different approach? Am I initializing the property twice therefore, using more memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing is bad design. Make the `propertyToInitialize` an Optional wrapping a CGRect, so that it doesn't need a value at initialization time, and move your code to your view's `didMoveToSuperview`, which is the first moment where the concept of a superview has any meaning. Even better, don't make this a property at all; the superview can be examined at anytime you need this information, so it's pointless to duplicate it in a property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the best approach for me is an Optional. Isn't there a `Lazy` type of property within swift that allows you to set a property once needed?

Comment: Yes, there is. Or you could use a calculated property so that this thing _looks_ like a property but in fact is a function that examines the superview in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best approach for me was.

**Code**

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    lazy var propertyToInitialize: CGRect = self.initializeProperty()

    //Custom Initializer
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func initializeProperty() -> CGRect {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (superview?.frame.size.width)!, height: (superview?.frame.size.height)!)
        return rect
    }
}
```

I think this is the best answer because I do not use the property until it is needed. And, can still get the superview size but not have to *double initialize*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `super.init` before you can access any properties in `self`, and put it into an entirely different function.

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    var propertyToInitialize: CGRect?

    init(frame: CGRect, property: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.propertyToInitialize = property
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //Decode propertyToInitialize
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. Try it.

Comment: @matt I didn't realise that, sorry. I'll just update my code.

Comment: @matt I just updated my code. Hopefully everything works now :)

Comment: Fine. :) Of course, _now_ you've simply repeated the answer I already gave (i.e. use an Optional). But that's okay.

Comment: @matt I hadn't seen your answer when I wrote this :)

Comment: No problem. We agree so we're both brilliant. :)